# Why doesn't std::sort doesn't work on std::list?

Tags: c++

Due to `std::sort` on a `std::list`, I receive the following errors:

```
line 44         : instantiated from here
line 5258 : error: no match for 'operator-' in '_last -__first'
line 179 : note: candidates are: ptrdiff_t std::operator-(const std::_Bit_iterator_base&, const std::_Bit_iterator_base&)
```

From the following code:

```
int main()
{
    std::list<Student_info> students;
    Student_info record;
    string::size_type maxlen = 0;   // the length of the longest name

    // read and store all the students data.
    while (read(cin, record))
    {
        // find length of longest name
        maxlen = max(maxlen, record.name.size());
        students.push_back(record);
    }

    // alphabetize the student records
    std::sort(students.begin(), students.end(), compare);

    return 0;
}
```

**What causes these errors? How can I sort this list?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your error means that the sort function was trying to use subtraction on the iterators.  Only random access iterators support this operation.  `std::list` has Bi-Directional iterators.  `std::sort` only works with random access iterators.  Luckily, `std::list` [has it's own sort function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/sort).

```
students.sort(compare);
```

Comment: understandable answer, thought so, there something that I don't understand(personal base knowledge), I can figure out later after learning more from the book thought, so no problem about it, whatsoever, tq for answer...

Answer (score 3):

use list member function sort

```
students.sort(compare);
```